# Images height bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, height

Can someone explain this? Images height doesn't render properly in Chrome but does just fine in every other browser... The first image of the section "RIDM" is a good exemple of the problem.

Here's my website: http://www.maximebourgeois.com/

It might have something to do with this Jquery command:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
$('section img').each(function(){
    if ($(this).width()/$(this).height() >= 1) {
        $(this).addClass('landscape');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('portrait');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting three 404 not founds and 20 validation errors. Might want to also fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s because you have a `max-height` set on the images; they are stopping at 550px.

Instead of:

```
section img.portrait {max-height:550px; width:auto; height:100%;}
```

You could try:

```
section img.portrait { width:100%; height:auto;}
```

Because height percentages work based on the parent element size, if you wanted to keep the maximum height of 550px you should make the parent element 550px high, so:

```
section ul li{
    height: 550px;
}

section img.portrait{
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 550px;
}
```

Comment: I do need to keep the maximum height of 550px, but chrome doesn't seems to like the 'max-height:550px;' command. even if I remove the 'height: 100%;'